# Self-defined Container about define iterator class using typedef

Tags: c++, templates, iterator

```
class iterator {
        typedef forward_iterator_tag iterator_category;
        typedef T value_type;
        typedef ptrdiff_t difference_type;
        typedef T* pointer;
        typedef T& reference;

        // functions:
        ...
};
```

Some Question:

1) what does typedef do here?

2) Is typedef necessary here?

3) Is typedef the standard convention in self-defined container's iterator here?

Comment: It defines type aliases private local to the class.

Comment: I forget to add keyword public.

Comment: Your question is still extremely unclear. It's pretty easy to know what `typedef` does in a particular scope. If you're asking for the semantics, your question appears to be _too broad_.

Comment: Please note that you can also use the syntax `using iterator_category = forward_iterator_tag`, which has exactly the same behaviour but might feel more natural